# Need to add Buy Now button as well as add to cart button in Magento

Tags: magento-1.9, addtocart, ce-1.9.2.2

I want to add both buttons "Buy Now" as well as "Add to Cart", If the user clicks on Buy-now it will redirect to the "onestepcheckout" page directly (Magento extension), for Add to Cart need default functionality. I'm using Magento 1.9.2.4

Please suggest how to add both functionalities without extension.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Magento 1.9 How to add buy now button in product page?](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/123072/magento-1-9-how-to-add-buy-now-button-in-product-page)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please add this in your phtml file where you want to add :

```
<div class="add-to-cart">
        <div class="qty-view">
        <?php if(!$_product->isGrouped()): ?>
        <label for="qty"><?php echo $this->__('Qty:') ?></label>
        <input type="text" name="qty" id="qty" maxlength="12" value="<?php echo $this->getProductDefaultQty() * 1 ?>" title="<?php echo $this->__('Qty') ?>" class="input-text qty validate-greater-than-zero-qty validate-digits" />
        <?php endif; ?>
        </div>
        <button type="button" class="button btn-cart" onclick="productAddToCartForm.submit(this)"><span><span><?php echo $buttonTitle ?></span></span></button>
        <button type="button" title="Buy Now" class="button btn-cart" onclick="setcheckoutLocation('<?php echo $this->getAddToCartUrl($_product) ?>')"><span><span>Buy Now</span></span></button>
        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('', true, true) ?>
</div>
```

and must be added this script for Buy Now button :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function setcheckoutLocation(location)
{
    showLoadingAnimation();
    jQuery.ajax({
        type:"GET",
        url:location,
        success:function(data){
            window.location.href = "<?php echo Mage::helper('checkout/url')->getCheckoutUrl(); ?>";
        }
    });
}
</script>
```

Comment: thanks for response, but it didn't work, still its redirect me to checkout/cart. :(

Comment: please tell me what happen with this code:?

Comment: it didn't redirect me to onestepcheckout page. It works as default after click on buy now, it takes to checkout/cart page.

Comment: can you send me your url link?

Comment: so, basically its not working with configurable products. fine with simple one.

Comment: I used this code too, but it doesn't work with configurable and simple with custom options. Any amendments?